# How to put description on top of the input box, for a new field added to comment form?

Tags: forms, comments

I have added a new field to my comment form and this is how my comment form look liks:

[image]

So you can see it does not look nice, I want to have the description on top of the input box, where I say: Which paragraph do you want to put comment on?(Enter 0 if you ant to put comment on the whole article). So How can I do it?

This is the function that I have used to add the new field to comment form:

```
  function Annotations_form_comment_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
$form['paragraph_id'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t('Which paragraph you want to put comment on?(Enter 0 if you want to put comment on the whole article.)') . "<br>",
    '#required' => TRUE,
    '#size' => 10,
    '#maxlength' => 2,
    '#default_value' => !empty($form['#entity']->paragraph_id) ? $form['#entity']->paragraph_id : NULL, // set the default value to the current paragraph value
    '#weight' => $form['subject']['#weight'] + 1, // place after the subject field by setting the weight to +1 of subject weight
);

$form['#validate'][] = 'annotations_form_comment_form_validate';
$form['#submit'][] = 'annotations_form_comment_form_submit';
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a description field to your array:

```
$form['paragraph_id'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t('Your Title'),
    '#description' => t('The paragraph you would like to put a comment on (enter 0 if you want to put the comment on the entire article'),
    ...
);
```

This way the explanation will show up under the field.

Comment: Thank you, it worked, So what if I want to have the field under the description?@Klaus Sonnenleiter

Comment: I think that's a matter of how your theme will arrange things on the page. Without getting too deep into it, and since theming is quite a large field to get familiar with, it's probably easiest, if you simply download a couple of themes and see how they change your look and feel.

Once you're comfortable with changing templates, look for "*.tpl.php" files in your theme's folder.

Comment: thanks, so what about comment part? You can see that the "Comment" is on one line, and under it is the comment input box. How can I have something like that?

Comment: This is done in the "Manage Display" section of your content type. I think what you want is to set the label to "inline" instead of "above".